# Execute method after all promises inside of a given method resolved

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

In a Vue.js component, I have some methods that use [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) to call an API.

In different cases, I need to execute some code once the call in this method has resolved, but I don't want to add a bunch of `if` statements in the `.then()` chained to the axios call.

```
methods: {
  callApi() {
    axios.get('/api')
     .then(() => {
       // call has resolved, request is done
     })
  },
  firstMethod() {
    this.callApi()
    // Need to wait for the call to resolve
    // Do something
  },
  secondMethod() {
    this.callApi()
    // Need to wait for the call to resolve
    // Do something else
  }
}
```

As you can see, `firstMethod` and `secondMethod` both rely on `callApi` but are supposed to do a different thing once the request is done. I prefer to split this logic in different functions instead of using conditions in the `callApi` method.
Is there a way to do this without having to add this logic inside of the 
`callApi` ?

Comment: Does the execution condition for both the methods, rely on the response of `callApi`?

Comment: return the `axios.get()` call from within `callApi()`, so you can continue the `.then()` chain inside `firstMethod()` and `secondMethod()` seperately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have `callApi` return the promise chain, then use and return that in `firstMethod` and `secondMethod`.

```
methods: {
  callApi() {
    return axios.get('/api')
     .then(() => {
       // call has resolved, request is done
     })
  },
  firstMethod() {
    return this.callApi()
    .then(() => {
      // Need to wait for the call to resolve
      // Do something
    })
  },
  secondMethod() {
    return this.callApi()
    .then(() => {
      // Need to wait for the call to resolve
      // Do something else
    })
  }
}
```

Whatever calls `callApi`, `firstMethod`, or `secondMethod` should check for failure and handle/report it.

---

Your original code was breaking one of the rules of promises: The function should always either return the chain, or handle rejection. (And yes, that's *or* [99.9% of the time], not *and*.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, very helpful! Where can I find the *rules* of promises ?

Comment: @GrahamSlick - Any good book discussion JavaScript promises should cover them. (Sadly, mine isn't out until September. :-) ) The main ones are the one above and [not creating promises unnecessarily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it).

Answer (score 1):

Promises chain, so you need to take the promise that Axios returns, perform any handling you might need to do, then return it from your `callApi` method. In your other methods where you're calling `callApi` you handle the returned promise and put any code that has to run after the API has responded in the handler function.

```
callApi() {
  return axios.get('/api')
   .then(() => {
     // this gets handled first
   })
},
firstMethod() {
  this.callApi()
  .then(() => {
    // this gets handled second
  })
},
secondMethod() {
  this.callApi()
  .then(() => {
    // or this gets handled second
  })
}
```